# Python counting the number of occurence in csv file based on dependence and independence list

Tags: python, csv

I want to write the count dependence into the last column of CSV, however, it only displays at the first column of the CSV. Another problem I faced is that it is supposed to display the occurrence of dependence for each row but it only displays one time only.
My goal is to display my data at the occurrence of the dependence column.It is supposed to display 0 and 1 instead of 1 only.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMNG2.png

```
writer = csv.writer(read_obj)
writer.writerow([countdependence])
```

After I added the above code it gave me the result of

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA58a.png

```
  dependence=['customer','team','job']
countdependence = 0

    with open('importantdata.csv', 'r+',encoding='utf-8', newline='') as read_obj:
    
        for i in read_obj:
            for word in dependence:
                if word in i.lower():
                    countdependence += 1
                    writer = csv.writer(read_obj)
                    writer.writerow([countdependence])
            print(countdependence)
            countdependence=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dependence=['customer','team','job']
countdependence = 0
with open('importantdata.csv', 'r',encoding='utf-8', newline='\n') as read_obj:
    # reading by row
    for row in read_obj:
        # for each word in the dependence array
        for word_in_dependence in dependence:
            # checks if the word in dependence is in the row
            if word_in_dependence in row.lower():
                countdependence += 1
        print(countdependence)
```

Comment: Well, that's another question. You should search how to write in the csv file. To give you a hint, you are opening the file with permission only to read it. Hope it helps you.

Comment: yeah my above code does that

Comment: i  have modified my code but it did not display my data of countdependence into the column of occurence of dependence in the csv file, it display at the first row instead. Another error i get is that i only display the count dependence of 1 for one row only but it is supposed to display 0 1 for two rows.